# C++ Friend constructor

Tags: c++

I have two classes : `Point`, that lives only in `Space`

```
class Point
{
private:
    Point(const Space &space, int x=0, int y=0, int z=0);
    int x, y, z;
    const Space & m_space;
};
```

The constructor is intentionally private, I don't want it to be called directly.
I'd like to create Points this way

```
Space mySpace;
Point myPoint = mySpace.Point(5,7,3);
```

Is there any way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Research [`friend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) classes and functions.

Comment: *The constructor is intentionally private*... why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, declare `Space::Point()` as a friend method.  That method will receive access to `Point`'s private members.

```
class Point
{
public:
    friend Point Space::Point(int, int, int);
private:
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't like to use the same name as the constructor :
declaration of 'Point Space::Point(int, int, int) changes meaning of 'Point' from 'struct Point'. I guess I should just rename it.

Comment: @user2578002 You could also use a fully-qualified name when creating the Point object, such as `your::namespace::Point(x, y, z)`.

Comment: Why the ctor's signature is inconsistent with being inferred at other place? For disambiguation?

Comment: @LIUQingyuan I don't understand the question. Inconsistent with which "other place?"

Comment: @cdhowie nevermind, my bad, got the wrong idea at the very beginning

Comment: @cdhowie Is it a specific design pattern?

Answer (score 7):

I would do it like this:

```
class Space
{
public:
    class Point
    {
    private:
        Point(const Space &space, int x=0, int y=0, int z=0);
        int m_x, m_y, m_z;
        const Space & m_space;

    friend class Space;
    };

    Point MakePoint(int x=0, int y=0, int z=0);
};
```

```
Space::Point::Point(const Space &space, int x, int y, int z)
    : m_space(space), m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z)
{
}

Space::Point Space::MakePoint(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return Point(*this, x, y, z);
}
```

```
Space mySpace;
Space::Point myPoint = mySpace.MakePoint(5,7,3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, problem is, that I will have to do always refer to the Space class to manipulate points
mySpace.p1 + mySpace.p2, I'll keep nested class in mind

Comment: Actually, you can make Space and Point *not* nested, that will work fine (you don't need to nest friend classes). However, nesting is a better approach for this situation - classes are closely related.

Comment: Is it a specific design pattern?